# xset: unable to open display

Tags: power-management, monitor, xset

For the longest time after about 5 minutes my screen would blank out. Now the screen will go blank after 5 minutes but then 2 seconds after that it will light up white and keep the laptop backlighting on. I didn't change any settings to my knowledge it just happened randomly after powering it on one day and has occurred since then.

I wish to resort back to blanking the screen out completely since I leave this computer on all the time and it's hard to sleep with a huge white light all the time.

`xset dpms force off` just yields me:

```
xset:  unable to open display ""
```

Answer (score 14):

You need to tell `xset` which display to use:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
xset q
```

Comment: > export DISPLAY=:0 > xset q after that I have ' unable to open display ":0" '

Comment: Had same problem when was trying to access monitor remotely with user other than logged in.

Comment: Then I get `xset:  unable to open display ":0"`

Comment: `export DISPLAY=0` instead. It should work

Comment: Neither of the methods works in systemd foked process.

Comment: For me a combination of `sudo` & running the normal command worked. Combination of `export DISPLAY=:0` and `sudo xset q`. Pretty weird.

Answer (score 3):

Try `vbetool` instead `xset`:

```
sudo vbetool dpms off
```

It's works fine for me.

Comment: Sorry I got the error "Real mode call failed"

Comment: I got "Failed to initialise LRMI (Linux Real-Mode Interface)."